# Powershell 1.0 - loop to replace text in aspx file will not work

Tags: loops, powershell, replace, iteration

I have the loop:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*\login.aspx' | ForEach {

  (Get-Content $_.FullName) | ForEach {

    $_ -replace "<title>Welcome to Synergy!</title>","<title>Welcome!</title>"

  } | Set-Content $_.FullName

}
```

And it does nothing to the subdirectories of wwwroot?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. I wasn't putting in the full path of the Get-Childitem argument